# How to execute PHP mysqli multi query by setting variables

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to execute a multi query in `PHP` `MySQL`, and get the result. My queries are like this.

```
$sql1 = "set @uid:=(select chat_id from chat_notify where online=1 and engaged=0 limit 1);";
$sql1 .= "update chat_notify set engaged=1,emp_id=1 where chat_id=@uid;";
$sql1 .= " select @uid";

$sql = $mysqli->multi_query($sql1);
```

I want to get the result of the `uid` in `php`.

Comment: There's no need for `multi_query()` because each query is a separate SQL query. Just execute them separately.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code accordingly

```
$sql1 = "set @uid:=(select chat_id from chat_notify where online=1 and engaged=0 limit 1)";
$sql2 = "update chat_notify set engaged=1,emp_id=1 where chat_id=@uid";
$sql3 = "select @uid";

$mysqli->query($sql1);
$mysqli->query($sql2);
$res = $mysqli->query($sql3);
```

and then get your query result usual way

Comment: You don't need it. Especially being a fresher